# LTE-Advanced Network Topology

Tags: networking, lte

I have been searching around for a LTE-A network topology but not sure if was looking for a correct one..

I was given a hint by my lecturer, there shall be 5 vital hardwares in the network.

I would like to ask if the other 3 shall be `end-device,server,switch`?

> 1)Antenna/Transmission tower
>
> 2)Router/gateway
>
> 3)
>
> 4)
>
> 5)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the rest of the Hardwares might be e-NodeB,Server,UE

Answer (score 0):

Refer to 36.300 standard in 3GPP.

Answer (score 0):

In LTE, and and LTE Advanced, there are core network components which are as follows;

1- eNodeB
2- MME (Mobility Management Entity)
3- SGW (Service Gateway)
4- PGW (Packet Gateway)
5- HSS (Home Subscriber Server)
6- PCRF (Policy Control Rule/Ruling Function)

These might be additional components depending on different video, voice (VoLTE) services that will be implemented in the network.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need more details.